# Splitting a list into alphabetic ranges

Tags: c#, list

I need to split a list into multiple lists that are grouped according to the first character of a string property. Here's an example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var makes = new List<VehicleMake>
                        {
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Acura"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "AMG"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Audi"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "BMW"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Chevrolet"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Datsun"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Eagle"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Fiat"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Honda"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Infiniti"},
                            new VehicleMake {Name = "Jaguar"}
                        };

        var balancedLists = makes.Balance(new List<BalancedListGroup>
                          {
                              new BalancedListGroup { RangeStart = 'A', RangeEnd = 'C'},
                              new BalancedListGroup { RangeStart = 'D', RangeEnd = 'F'},
                              new BalancedListGroup { RangeStart = 'G', RangeEnd = 'J'},
                          });

        foreach (var balancedList in balancedLists)
        {
            foreach (var vehicleMake in balancedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(vehicleMake.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class VehicleMake
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class VehicleMakeListBalancer
{
    public static List<List<VehicleMake>> Balance(this List<VehicleMake> list, List<BalancedListGroup> groups)
    {
        var letters =
            new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "y", "z" };
        var balancedLists = new List<List<VehicleMake>>();
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var groupList = new List<VehicleMake>();
            for (var i = letters.IndexOf(group.RangeStart.ToString().ToLower()); i <= letters.IndexOf(group.RangeEnd.ToString().ToLower()); i++)
            {
                groupList.AddRange(list.Where(l => l.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(letters[i].ToString())).ToList());
            }
            balancedLists.Add(groupList);
        }

        return balancedLists;
    }
}

public class BalancedListGroup
{
    public char RangeStart { get; set; }
    public char RangeEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Acura
AMG
Audi
BMW
Chevrolet
---
Datsun
Eagle
Fiat
---
Honda
Infiniti
Jaguar
---
```

This algorithm works, but feels very clumsy. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following extention method uses linq to select all the vehicle makes whose name starts in range of characters.

```
        public static List<VehicleMake> GetInRange(this List<VehicleMake> vehicleList, char RangeStart, char RangeEnd)
        {
            var vehiclesInRange = from vm in vehicleList
                                  where vm.Name[0] >= RangeStart && vm.Name[0] <= RangeEnd
                                  select vm;

            return vehiclesInRange.ToList();
        }
```

**USAGE SAMPLE**

```
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var makes = new List<VehicleMake> { 
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Acura" },
                new VehicleMake { Name = "AMG" },
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Audi" }, 
                new VehicleMake { Name = "BMW" }, 
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Chevrolet" },
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Datsun" },
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Eagle" }, 
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Fiat" },
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Honda" }, 
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Infiniti" },
                new VehicleMake { Name = "Jaguar" } 
            }; 


            var atoc =  makes.GetInRange('A', 'C');
            atoc.Print();

            var dtom = makes.GetInRange('D', 'M');
            dtom.Print();

            var mtoz = makes.GetInRange('M', 'Z');
            mtoz.Print();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static List<VehicleMake> GetInRange(this List<VehicleMake> vehicleList, char RangeStart, char RangeEnd)
        {
            var vehiclesInRange = from vm in vehicleList
                                  where vm.Name[0] >= RangeStart && vm.Name[0] <= RangeEnd
                                  select vm;

            return vehiclesInRange.ToList();
        }

        static void Print(this List<VehicleMake> vehicles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            vehicles.ForEach(v => Console.WriteLine(v.Name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ugh, I was so close to this when I started writing this algorithm, except I tried to do this on the whole string and not just the first character. This is perfect though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy()` to achieve what you want - group by the first letter of your vehicle, then make sublists of those:

```
var balancedLists = makes.GroupBy(x => x.Name[0]).Select( x=> x.ToList())
                         .ToList();
```

This will however create groups that only cover one letter each - to modify the grouping behavior you could provide a custom method `GetGroup( char c)` that returns an integer to identify the group.

Alternatively, if all you want is *balanced* groups, you could use the index to group the vehicles into same-size groups:

```
var balancedLists = makes.Select((vehicle, index) => new { Index = index, Vehicle = vehicle })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Vehicle).ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this example only groups by the first letter. I need the groups to be ranged. In my example, I'm expecting 3 lists. One with all makes starting with A-C, one with all makes starting with D-F, and one with all makes starting with G-J. The lines with three hypens in the sample output delimit each list that's output by my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd have an object with the following invariants:

- Can host a number of balancedlistgroup items
- For a given Vehicle passed in returns e.g. an integer that is the same for any Vehicle falling within a given range

Then you can group your list of vehicles with the aid of that object:

```
var groups = vehicles.GroupBy(x => rangeContainer.GroupKey(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this query will do what you need efficiently:

```
var letterGroupTuples 
    = from blGroup in groups
      from letter in Enumerable.Range
                 (blGroup.RangeStart, blGroup.RangeEnd - blGroup.RangeStart + 1)
      select new { Letter = char.ToLower((char)letter), BlGroup = blGroup };

var groupsForLetters = letterGroupTuples.ToDictionary
                       (a => a.Letter, a => a.BlGroup);

var query = from vehicleMake in list
            let key = vehicleMake.Name.ToLower().First()
            where groupsForLetters.ContainsKey(key)
            group vehicleMake by groupsForLetters[key] into bucket
            select bucket.ToList();

return query.ToList();
```

The idea is to:

1. Create a hash-table from *valid* letters to the associated bucket.
2. Group items into the right bucket  using the hash-table, filtering out those items that do not have a corresponding bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Another Linq option if you like.

```
        var makes = new List<VehicleMake> {
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Acura" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "AMG" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Audi" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "BMW" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Chevrolet" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Datsun" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Eagle" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Fiat" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Honda" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Infiniti" }, 
            new VehicleMake { Name = "Jaguar" } };


        var balancedLists = new List<BalancedListGroup> 
        { 
            new BalancedListGroup { RangeStart = 'A', RangeEnd = 'C' }, 
            new BalancedListGroup { RangeStart = 'D', RangeEnd = 'F' }, 
            new BalancedListGroup { RangeStart = 'G', RangeEnd = 'J' }, 
        };

        List<List<VehicleMake>> brandedMakes = new List<List<VehicleMake>>();
        foreach (var x in balancedLists)
        {
            brandedMakes.Add(makes.Where(a => a.Name.Substring(0, 1)[0] >= x.RangeStart && a.Name.Substring(0, 1)[0] < x.RangeEnd).ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my 2p in:

I started out by assuming a very bad thing, to simplify my code. Namely that you're working with upper case ascii characters for your initial letters. Obviously my code can be modified to work with your range structures.

So I get my initial ranges like so:

```
var initialGroups = new List<IEnumerable<char>> 
                  { 
                    Enumerable.Range((int)'A', 3).Select(i => (char)i)
                  , Enumerable.Range((int)'D', 3).Select(i => (char)i)
                  , Enumerable.Range((int)'G', 4).Select(i => (char)i) 
                  };
```

And the method to get the groups is:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GroupByInitial(List<string> cars, List<IEnumerable<char>> initialGroups)
{
    var groups = from grp in initialGroups
                 from car in cars 
                 where grp.Contains(car[0])
                 select new {grp, car};
    return groups.GroupBy(group => group.grp).Select(group => group.Select(grouping => grouping.car));
}
```